# How to show ContextMenuStrip on C# Form?

Tags: c#, contextmenu

I am trying to get C#'s form to have a contextmenu at the top of the form to where options already show up on load and you can click it to get more of a dropdown, how would I do this? Thanks

Comment: Do you need a menu strip (MenuStrip class)?

Comment: Yes I need a menu strip. Oh! Thanks you helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are asking for a `MenuStrip` control:

http://en.csharp-online.net/Create_and_configure_a_MenuStrip

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menustrip.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Hope these help

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/toolbars/customtoolstrip.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/MfcWinFormsOff.aspx